# Rank Selection in Genetic Algorithm for Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Me and my group are currently working on a project where we use genetic algorithm using rank based selection for it. Tried looking for implementation using c# code but to no avail. Also tried looking for implementation in different languages but it is hard to understand in languages that I have not much experience on. Are there pseudo codes that could help us in understanding and implementing it ourselves? An example in c# code would be appreciated as well. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the c# implementation of NSGAII for Grasshopper https://github.com/sofia-feist/NSGA_II For a basic understanding of GAs (and rankings in GA) I recommend the book Genetic Algorithms in Search, Optimization and Machine Learning by Goldberg. For NSGA II, you can look at Deb's paper and codes: [https://www.egr.msu.edu/~kdeb/codes.shtml](https://www.egr.msu.edu/%7Ekdeb/codes.shtml)